# Is there something like private items in Basecamp?

Tags: privacy, collaboration, basecamp

While in [Basecamp classic](http://basecamp.com/classic) you were able to mark todo-lists or messages as private (only visible by your company), it seems that there's no such feature in the ["all-new" version of Basecamp](https://basecamp.com).

I know that you can set permissions for whole projects in way that only your company is able to access the project and that you can move whole todo-lists to another project. But that's an annoying and complicated workflow.

Is there another easy workflow which simulates the **Private Items** feature from Basecamp classic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This has been implemented to the new basecamp a while ago (in 2013).

Answer (score 1):

You're in good company - a lot of people miss the *Private* facilities (nice write-up [here](http://needmoredesigns.com/blog/a-tale-of-two-basecamps/)).

In one of 37Signal's early communications during the release of the new system, they stated that they are "rethinking" Private, and that they may add support for this in the future.

When you look at their "[New stuff](http://basecamp.com/announcements)" link, you can tell that they're working hard on things - so I tend to believe that Private indeed will return (in some way) in the future.

**Update!**: Basecamp now supports this via [Client Projects](https://basecamp.com/1679267/announcements/30).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in ProofHub ( https:/proofhub.com) which I think is far much better than new and classic basecamp. Very simple and easy to use application wherein discussions, To-do's , Timesheets, Notes, Calendar and Files management is supereasy....

Comment: This doesn't really help answer the question asked. Do you work for ProofHub, or is this something you've used in the past?